# MIT App inventor - how to set different values to items in a list?

Tags: app-inventor

How to do this in App Inventor?

[image]

The overall problem is that I have list items in text format, and the app is connected to the DB via php. I know I could solve the problem in seconds on php, but I really need to solve this in app inventor.
I need to convert text list item into an id number.

Edit:
Here is the full AI2 code.[blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCRMs.png)
This needs to work in a way so it will display the input in my DB as id_numbers and not strings in the item list.

Comment: Please show an example of your list. The most basic way is to use the index values for the numbers (AI2 indexes start at 1, not 0). For example if your list is "Green,Red,Blue" then Green is at index 1, Red is at index 2, and so on. You can make an AI2 list from your list by using the "list from csv row" block, or "list from csv table" block if you have more than one row in your list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please replace your first one-line image with text formatted as code?

Comment: Thanks for the blocks image, but it would also help if you showed the responseContent from your Web1.GET, then we can tell you what you need to do with it.